# Calabash iOS launches the default simulator even after defining DEVICE_TARGET

Tags: jenkins, ios-simulator, calabash, calabash-ios

In Jenkins I am passing the following to the shell:

```
DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)'
cucumber features/Login_FR.feature
```

However the cucumber script keeps launching device iPhone 5 (8.1 Simulator).

When I run DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)' from the terminal all works as expected.

I've blown away the derived data, cleaned and rebuilt from Xcode and reset the simulator. That did not seem to cure the problem. Is there something cached in the Jenkins job that keeps telling the script to run iPhone 5 (8.1 Simulator)?

Is there another way to define what device is to be launched from either the pre_stop_hooks or the launch.rb?

Comment: I may have figured it out, but we'll see it could return. I never built iPhone 5 (8.1 Simulator) in Xcode and for an unknown reason cucumber was defaulting to that sim version and ignoring my DEVICE_TARGET variable. However when i finally built it in the one it was defaulting to it then start using the DEVICE_TARGET I specified. GO figure : /

Comment: Can you clarify how you called cucumber?  From your code block, I see 2 lines.  Was the entire command on the same line? If not, I don't think DEVICE_TARGET was being defined correctly for the cucumber command.  You'd have to use `export DEVICE_TARGET=` to get the correct behavior.  I am glad you got it this running, but building for the correct simulator in Xcode has nothing to do with which Simulator is launched by Calabash.  Have a look at this wiki page: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Hot-Topics.  Gist: https://gist.github.com/jmoody/7543629290b7e192a261

Comment: yes it was on the same line. I figured that problem out later. thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DEVICE_TARGET='iPad 2 (8.1 Simulator)' cucumber
```

replace the value given to device_target with whatever simulator that you need to use.

Comment: run that at the terminal- and you can also add an alias -ipad_cucumber runs the above command for me.